# Can a contract run out of gas?

Tags: solidity, gas, out-of-gas, gas-limit

If a contract is to send a given amount of tokens or ether to lets say, 10,000 different addresses, will it run out of gas? If so, what will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple transaction consumes `21,000` units of gas.

Hence `10,000` transactions will consume `21,000 x 10,000 = 210,000,000`units of gas.

As long as sufficient gas is provided, the contract will execute and not run out of gas.

Comment: Have to account for block gas limit also. It's ~8,000,000 right now.